# How to fix overflow issue when zoomin on desktop(mobile responsive website)

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport, device-width

I am implementing a plugin where users can zoom in and out of web content as they wanted. The plugin is going to be implemented to any mobile responsive websites.
I implemented the zoom in using

**For FireFox**

```
$('body').css('MozTransform','scale(2)');
```

**For Chrome**

```
$('body').css('zoom', ' 200%');
```

I have attached the images at the bottom.
Here **right and bottom black bar** is plugin part.
The problem is **Desktop zoomin view**.
Overflow happen and contents overflow are hidden. So when users click zoom in button on desktop, I would like to show zoomin version of mobile not zoomin version of desktop view.

I tried to fix this by changing or adding viewport metatag using Javascript.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=400, initial-scale=0.86, maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=0.86">`

Here 400 is width of mobile device.

But it changed nothing.

Seems it can be easily solved if I can set `device-width` using Javascript, but not found solution yet.

I have been working on this issue for 2 days and anyone who have experienced this field, appreciate your help!

Is it even possible?

### Desktop original view:

[image]

### Desktop zoomed view:

[image]

### Mobile original view:

[image]

Comment: Why do you show zoom buttons on desktop? You said it is responsive website..

Comment: yes, it's responsive website - I am implementing a plugin which can be integrated to any website so that users can see zoomin version and zoomout version of website. for example can see big letters.

Comment: Yep. So you can show/hide boxes based on resolution...

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I only have control of plugin buttons.